# Using the same custom domain (different subdomains) in 2 separate Firebase projects. Is this possible?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, custom-domain

I'd like to have 2 firebase projects for two separate environments. `dev` and `prod`.

- `my-project-prod`
- `my-project-dev`

If I have a single custom domain: `www.mydomain.com`

Can I use that same custom domain in those 2 different projects?

I would use different subdomains. Example:

- `my-project-prod` would be connected to `www.mydomain.com`
- `my-project-dev` would be connected to `dev.mydomain.com`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you click add custom domain in firebase hosting, for one, type in [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and add the resource records. For the other domain, type in dev.mydomain.com and add the resource records. When you add the 2 A records, make the host dev, instead of @ or www.